# jQuery Minimal Menu links not working

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hyperlink

I'm newbie to jQuery and Im' using a minimal menu with jQuery triger. I've linked the hyperlinks in this menu but its not clickable even not working. It seems that jQuery `defaultprevent()` is blocking links. When I remove `defaultprevent()` lines from jquery-1.4.min.js, links starts working but the menu trigger / hover went away.

Can anyone help me? I want hyperlinks to work with menu hover/trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Your menu doesn't work i think because there is a click handler that return false:

```
$("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five,#six,#seven,#eight").lavaLamp({
fx: "backout",
speed: 700,
click: function(event, menuItem) {
return false;
}
```

try taking off the last part

```
$("#one,#two,#three,#four,#five,#six,#seven,#eight").lavaLamp({
fx: "backout",
speed: 700
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this...
and put `.preventDefault()` back into jQuery

```
$("#one").lavaLamp({
    fx: "backout", 
    speed: 700,
    click: function(event, menuItem) {
         window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```